# What is a shaggy-dog story?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

Can anybody help me to explain the meaning of this sentence, i dont understand its meaning, it's about when Andrew Marr (a Historian) make a conclusion about History of the World, he concluded about the entire human history:

***" It's all a shaggy-dog story of unexpected consequences."***

Comment: You apparently are not aware of this thing called "Google".

Comment: [Here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shaggy-dog_story) you can find what it means.

Comment: There used to be an Irish comedian called Dave Allen who was famous for his shaggy dog tales/jokes. His most famous one was of a funeral being led by a Doberman, I think it was. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mt7h3CghJEg

Comment: That's not it :)

Answer (score 1):

A ***shaggy dog story*** refers to *a  lengthy, improbable and ultimately pointless story, often told in an attempt at humour.*

Its  origin ( somehow related also to the most famous collie dog Lassie) according to [The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/shaggy-dog-story.html)  appears to be from an American phrase. Its first mention in print was probably in *Esquire magazine*, May 1937:

> - "One of the more sporting ways of finding out which ones are not [sane] is to try shaggy-dog stories on them."

The expression probably derives from an actual but improbable story about a shaggy dog.

> - There are a few contenders for the honour of being the first such story. For my money the one that is ***the most likely source of the phrase originates from the pen of the American author, dog breeder and journalist - Albert Payson Terhune.*** He was quite a celebrated author of animal stories, especially dog stories, in the early years of the 20th century. Terhune's best-known creation was Lad, the collie dog that took the lead, so to speak, in several popular books (and later a film), including his 1919 story Lad: A Dog. ***The later canine star Lassie is clearly modelled on Lad, who in Lad: A Dog tackles a poisonous snake, saves a crippled child and prevents the family barn from being burned down.***
> - On 6th November 1926 the Canadian paper The Manitoba Free Press printed a piece by Terhune, which he wrote as if it were a true account of a dog called Lad – who is described in the text as a ‘shaggy dog’. ***The tediously detailed and meandering story certainly fits the bill of 'shaggy dog story',*** in that it requires us to believe that the hero survived shooting, clubbing and burial and came bounding back for more. The account is of a stray collie that was shot for killing sheep and which the author claims it to be 'true in all but details'. It is headed The Strangest Dog Story I Know:
>
>   - *"I tied Lad to a tree" he said, "with a lot of good stout wire. Then I shot him three times in the head, at close range. Then I hammered his head with a club. Then I dug a grave two feet deep and buried him. He didn't suffer, though. He never moved after the first shot hit him."*...
>   - *"Imagine my astonishment, Sunday morning, three days later, when my little son rushed into my room, shouting:
>       'Dad, Laddie has come back. He still has the wire around him and there's a big hole in his neck! And he's all covered with earth.' There the dog stood on the front porch."...*

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia article [Shaggy Dog Story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaggy_dog_story) begins:

> "In its original sense, a shaggy dog story is an extremely long-winded anecdote characterized by extensive narration of typically irrelevant incidents and terminated by an anticlimax or a pointless punchline."

Comment: Or very feeble punchline. *Shaggy-dog stories* used to be quite fashionable in the sixties. I distinctly remember one about an unusual gigantic bird known as a *Rary*. After a convoluted story involving the adventures of one of these creatures, someone manages to load it on the back of a truck, with the intention of tipping it over a cliff. Of course the punch line is *Don't do it, it's a Long Way to Tip a Rary*